# Counter property does not change value

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a quiz in the Swift Playgrounds app and I want to keep a counter of the number of correct answers. The value of `correct` doesn't change, and I don't know why.

```
  var correct:Int = 0
    func qa(question: String, answer: String) {
    show(question)
    var ans = ask("answer")
    if (ans.lowercased() == answer) {
        show("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    } else {
        show("wrong you numpty!")
    }
}
     func qaor(question: String, answer: String, answer2: String) {
    show(question)
    var ans = ask("answer")
    if (ans.lowercased() == answer) || (ans.lowercased() == answer2) {
        show("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    } else {
        show("wrong you numpty!")
    }
}


show("What is your name?")

let name = ask("Name")

show("Hi " + name)

qa(question: "What is the name of the character played by Simon Jones in the Hitchikers Guide to the Galaxy?", answer: "arthur dent")

qaor(question: "What is voiced by Peter Jones in the Hitchikers Guide to the Galaxy?", answer: "the book", answer2: "the guide")

qa(question: "finish this sentence  .doing the coastlines was always my Favourite, the rough crinkley edges, .... ", answer: "fjords")

var cf = "no"
if (correct == 0) {
    var cf = "no"
} else if (correct == 1) {
    var cf = "one"
} else if (correct == 2) {
    var cf = "two"
} else if (correct == 3) {
    var cf = "three"
}

show("you got " + cf + " questions correct out of three")
```

Comment: Do not re-declare `cf` in your if-else block. just do `cf="no"`, etc.

Comment: Please format and indent your code at least according to *some* style guide. This code is unreadable and does not belong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not declare the `cf` variable for every if/else statement. It creates a local variable and you aren't changing the first `cf`.

Instead, try this:

```
var cf = "no"
if (correct == 0) {
    cf = "no"
} else if (correct == 1) {
    cf = "one"
} else if (correct == 2) {
    cf = "two"
} else if (correct == 3) {
    cf = "three" 
}

show("you got " + cf + " questions correct out of three")
```

Comment: Thank you berksy92 I just tested it and it works